# The word for the practice of manufacturing a plausible legal path to trapping a criminal using evidence gathered illegally

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm taking an example from law enforcement, but the word I'm looking for applies more broadly.

Let's say that a law enforcement agency used illegal means to gather evidence of a crime, for example, illegal surveillance. The agency needs to come up with a plausible way they caught the criminal without revealing that their actions were based on illegally gathered evidence.

To give a pratical example: a police force tapped phone conversations without a warrant and figured that a person would be transporting drugs in their car. The police force can't stop the car based on illegally gathered evidence, so instead, they just happen to stop that particular car during a random "routine traffic stop".

In more elaborate cases, agencies build a legal path to "artificially" arrive at a conclusion they originally got to through illegal surveillance.

What is the word for this practice?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110239/discussion-on-question-by-juicy-the-word-for-the-practice-of-manufacturing-a-pla).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Parallel construction* is a legal term for building a case on alternative evidence.

en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_construction

Answer (score 0):

The stop of the car is called a "pretext" stop.  The police simply stop the car for some minor (or major) traffic violation.  Say, having dead bugs on license plate, "foreign material on license plate", or changing lade w.o signalling.  Then when the police car carrying the drug sniffing dog is nearby, executing the stop and calling in the dog for a drug sweep, all within the "reasonable amount of time it should take to write the ticket.  Happens all the time, to good effect too.